# Need a recursive function to get all permutations of an array where each element is itself plus 0 to n

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion

Sorry for the wording of the title as I am unsure how to phrase the question.

I am trying to get all permutations of an array where each element could be it's value plus 0 to n ('wild' value)

e.g.

```
The array [0, 1, 0, 2, 1] with the wild value equal to 1 would have the permutations:
[1, 1, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 3, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 2]

The array [1, 2, 0, 0] with the wild value equal to 2 would have the permutations:
[3, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 1]
[1, 4, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 0]
[1, 3, 1, 0]
[1, 3, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 3, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
... and so on...
```

This is the code I have tried, but it is not producing the desired results:

```
def generateAllMatrices(length, buckets, ind, wild):  

    if ind == length: 
        # possible_buckets.append(buckets.copy())
        print(buckets)
        return

    if wild != 0:
        for i in range(1, wild + 1):
            buckets[ind] += 1
            generateAllMatrices(length, buckets, 0, wild - 1)
        buckets[ind] -= wild

    generateAllMatrices(length, buckets, ind + 1, wild)
```

An example result produced from the above code is:

```
Original = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Wild = 1

Permutations:
[2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Are there any similar algorithms I could reference for this? Or what route should I take regarding developing something that will produce what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
import itertools

def make_reps(l, wild):
    for indices in itertools.product(range(len(l)), repeat=wild): 
        new_l = list(l) 
        for i in indices: 
            new_l[i] += 1 
        yield new_l
```

With your given examples:

```
In [12]: list(make_reps([0, 1, 0, 2, 1], 1))                                                    
Out[12]: 
[[1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 2]]

In [14]: list(make_reps([1, 2, 0, 0], 2))                                                       
Out[14]: 
[[3, 2, 0, 0],
 [2, 3, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 1, 0],
 [2, 2, 0, 1],
 [2, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 3, 1, 0],
 [1, 3, 0, 1],
 [2, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 3, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 0, 1],
 [1, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 2]]
```